# Trying to create a circular menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a circular menu with radials using html and css, but the white borders are not built well. And it is not look fine in google chrome (not like a circle). I need get the last white radial, between item5 and item6. I have tried the next code:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RcLZJ/#run)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="item1 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#one">Solución Aula Digital</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item2 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#two">Live Streaming</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item3 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#three">Social Tecal Online</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item4 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#four">FlexScorn</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item5 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#five">Video On Demand</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper6">
        <div class="item6 item">
            <div class="content"><a href="#six">Video Colaboración</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #menu {
    background: #aaa;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 155px;
    -moz-border-radius: 90px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 90px;
  }
 #center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
#center a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.item {
    background: #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;

    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    -o-transition: background .5s;
    -ms-transition: background .5s;
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.item:hover {
    background: #eee
}
.item1 {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    width: 134px;
    height: 134px;
}
.item2 {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.item3 {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.item4 {
    z-index: 4;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
            width: 152px;
    height: 152px;
}
.item5 {
    z-index: 5;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
            width: 151px;
    height: 151px;
}
.item6 {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
#wrapper6 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    /*border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;*/
}



.item1 .content {
    left: 0px;
    top: 17px;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.item2 .content {
    left: -5px;
    top: 31px;
    transform: rotate(-59deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-59deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-59deg);
}
.item3 .content {
    left: -40px;
    top: 8px;
    transform: rotate(-237deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-237deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-237deg);
}
.item4 .content {
    left: -43px;
    top: 4px;
    transform: rotate(-240deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-240deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-240deg);
}
.item5 .content {
    left: -52px;
    top: 7px;
    transform: rotate(-247deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-247deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-247deg);
}
.item6 .content {
    left: 26px;
    top: -3px;
    transform: rotate(-29deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-29deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-29deg);
}
.content, .content a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
}
.content a {
    line-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff*/
}
.display-target {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}
.display-target:target {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade-in 1s;
    -moz-animation: fade-in 1s;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s;
    -o-animation: fade-in 1s;
    -ms-animation: fade-in 1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-o-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-ms-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

I need  get the six borders like this image :

[image]

Help, please!

Comment: Can you specify what "not built well" and "it does not look fine" mean?

Comment: not 'rounded', 'circular'...

Comment: your webkit vendor prefix is overriding the border radius of 155, that's why chrome's looks more square. get rid of the vendor prefixes

Comment: @KevinB, How can I get the last white border similar to the image?

Comment: @jarab I do not know.

Comment: You have completely changed the intent of your question. You should have instead accepted the correct answer and asked a new one.

Comment: I only added more information, to be more specific

Comment: You added a second half to the question. the original question was simply to make it round, you left the border portion off completely which is why you received two answers correcting the circle but not the border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `border-radius` was defined in `px` instead of %

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/RcLZJ/1/)

```
#menu {
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I need to get the last white radial between item5 and item6. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason it's not being a circle in Chrome:

```
border-radius: 155px;
-moz-border-radius: 90px;
-webkit-border-radius: 90px;
```

You're defining a different border radius for Webkit and Mozilla than for everyone else. Use the same value in all three styles.

Also:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

...will get you a circle no matter the size of the element.

Comment: I need to get the last white radial between item5 and item6. I updated the question.