# Trying to create a circular menu with 6 radials

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a circular menu with 6 radials using html and css. I only get 5 of the 6 total radials (borders). I need get the last radial, between item5 and item6. I need get the same of the picture:

[image: EXAMPLE]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RcLZJ/8/)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="item1 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#one">Solución Aula Digital</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item2 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#two">Live Streaming</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item3 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#three">Social Tecal Online</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item4 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#four">FlexScorn</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item5 item">
        <div class="content"><a href="#five">Video On Demand</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper6">
        <div class="item6 item">
            <div class="content"><a href="#six">Video Colaboración</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #menu {
    background: #aaa;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 155px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
}
#center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
#center a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.item {
    background: #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;

    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    -o-transition: background .5s;
    -ms-transition: background .5s;
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.item:hover {
    background: #eee
}
.item1 {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    width: 134px;
    height: 134px;
}
.item2 {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.item3 {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.item4 {
    z-index: 4;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
            width: 152px;
    height: 152px;
}
.item5 {
    z-index: 5;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
            width: 151px;
    height: 151px;
}
.item6 {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
#wrapper6 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    /*border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;*/
}



.item1 .content {
    left: 0px;
    top: 17px;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.item2 .content {
    left: -5px;
    top: 31px;
    transform: rotate(-59deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-59deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-59deg);
}
.item3 .content {
    left: -40px;
    top: 8px;
    transform: rotate(-237deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-237deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-237deg);
}
.item4 .content {
    left: -43px;
    top: 4px;
    transform: rotate(-240deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-240deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-240deg);
}
.item5 .content {
    left: -52px;
    top: 7px;
    transform: rotate(-247deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-247deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-247deg);
}
.item6 .content {
    left: 26px;
    top: -3px;
    transform: rotate(-29deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-29deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-29deg);
}
.content, .content a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
}
.content a {
    line-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff*/
}
.display-target {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}
.display-target:target {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade-in 1s;
    -moz-animation: fade-in 1s;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s;
    -o-animation: fade-in 1s;
    -ms-animation: fade-in 1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-o-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-ms-keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178493/trying-to-create-a-circular-menu ?

Comment: No duplicate, its different

Comment: Sorry, but that phrase: "I need get the last white radial, between item5 and item6." is in both questions. That's make me think that you're asking the same (get the white radial), it isn't?

Comment: You must read all the comments, then you will understand why a new question

Comment: As I see now, you have changed your old question to ask also for the white border? Please, if you already have posted this as a different question, revert the edit of the original question or the answer will make no sense for new users...

Comment: One user told me: "You have completely changed the intent of your question. You should have instead accepted the correct answer and asked a new one. By Kevin B"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a simple problem to get your line break in, albeit it is a little odd.

All I did was add an additional item without any content and then rotated it, gave it a background and transformed it into place.

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
width: 1px;
height: 70px;
left: 68px;
top: 81px;
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RcLZJ/10/)

The reason why you didn't have a white border there is because your `item6` was rotated so it lined up with your `item1`, instead of it being rotated so it created the border between `item5` and `item6`.

I tried rotating `item6` so it created the border between itself and 5, but it caused it to overlap with item1, which just caused a never ending z-index loop in order to solve it